Preventing or removing multiple instances of same range protected cells
I have two separate spreadsheets, one for admin and one for user.  The admin can lock or unlock certain ranges for either Fri, Sat, Sun or Holiday via onEdit trigger (ie fridaycheck().  When checkmark is removed those same ranges are removed.  The problem is when admin checkmarks all the boxes at once and before any of the separate scripts can complete.  When they finally do complete multiple protection instances exist for each of the days. When admin checks one day at a time and script is allowed to finish, everything works fine.  Looking to try and prevent multiple protection instances from being inserted OR remove all instances when the check mark is removed.  Here are the scripts for Fri onEdit check, lock and unlock.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks, Paul  
function fridaycheck() {
  let admincheck = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Admin")
  let activeCell = admincheck.getRange("AE9")
  let reference = activeCell.getA1Notation()
  let sheetName = activeCell.getSheet().getName()
  let activeValue = activeCell.getValue()
  if (reference == "AE9" && sheetName == "Admin" && activeValue == true)
    LockFriday();
  else 
    UnlockFriday();
  }

function LockFriday() {
  var protectRange = 'C8:D60';
  var description = 'AA Lock Friday Cells';
  var spreadsheet = 
SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
  spreadsheet.getRange(protectRange).activate();
  spreadsheet.setCurrentCell(spreadsheet.getRange('D60'));
  var p = spreadsheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE).find(e => 
e.getRange().getA1Notation() == protectRange && e.getDescription() == description);
  if (p) return;
  var protection = spreadsheet.getRange(protectRange).protect();
  var all = protection.getEditors();
  protection.setDescription(description).removeEditors(all);
  protection.setDescription(description).addEditor('xxx@gmail.com');
  protection.setDescription(description).addEditor('xxx@gmail.com');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var checkbox = ss.getRange("AE9").getValue();
  if(checkbox==false){
    ss.getRange("AE9").setValue("true");
  } 
} 

function UnlockFriday() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXXXXXXXXXXXX');
  spreadsheet.getRange('C8:D60').activate();
  var allProtections = 
spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  var matchingProtection1 = allProtections.find(existingProtection => existingProtection.getRange().getA1Notation() == 'C8:D60');
  if (!matchingProtection1) return;
  matchingProtection1.remove();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var checkbox = ss.getRange("AE9").getValue();
  if(checkbox==true){
    ss.getRange("AE9").setValue("false");
  } 
}


SUGGESTION
Based on your post, I understand that you want to ensure there are no duplicates of protected range descriptions, but only one unique protected range to be kept.
I suggest you could use the Advanced Google Service for Google Sheet API, as Advanced services are typically optimized for performance, which can lead to faster execution times.
I have tweaked your script and added how you can add the checkDupes sample function. Here's a sample tweaked script:
function fridaycheck() {
  let admincheck = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Admin")
  let activeCell = admincheck.getRange("AE9")
  let reference = activeCell.getA1Notation()
  let sheetName = activeCell.getSheet().getName()
  let activeValue = activeCell.getValue()
  if (reference == "AE9" && sheetName == "Admin" && activeValue == true)
    LockFriday();
  else
    UnlockFriday();
}

function LockFriday() {
  var protectRange = 'C8:D60';
  var description = 'AA Lock Friday Cells';
  var userSheetID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; //[UPDATED], placed the Sheet ID you are using in this 'userSheetID' variable for your 'LockFriday' function.
  var spreadsheet =
    SpreadsheetApp.openById(userSheetID); //[UPDATED], placed the 'userSheetID' variable to where it is needed
  spreadsheet.getRange(protectRange).activate();
  spreadsheet.setCurrentCell(spreadsheet.getRange('D60'));
  var p = spreadsheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE).find(e =>
    e.getRange().getA1Notation() == protectRange && e.getDescription() == description);
  if (p) return;
  var protection = spreadsheet.getRange(protectRange).protect();
  var all = protection.getEditors();
  protection.setDescription(description).removeEditors(all);
  protection.setDescription(description).addEditor('xxx@gmail.com');
  protection.setDescription(description).addEditor('xxx@gmail.com');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var checkbox = ss.getRange("AE9").getValue();
  if (checkbox == false) {
    ss.getRange("AE9").setValue("true");
  }

  checkDupes(userSheetID); //[UPDATED], added this function with the idea that every time a new protection is added, regardless of whether it is another duplicate, this function runs to make sure they are deleted.
}

function checkDupes(userSheetID) {
  var spreadsheetData = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(userSheetID); //Get data from the user spreadsheet via sheet ID
  var columns = Array.from({ length: 26 }, (_, i) => String.fromCharCode(97 + i).toUpperCase());

  //Function to trasnform result function into readable A1 notation range with description.
  let getReadableRanges = (p) => {
    return p.protectedRanges.map(r =>
      [r.protectedRangeId, r.description, `${columns.filter((_, i) => r.range.startColumnIndex == i)}${r.range.startRowIndex + 1}:${columns.filter((_, i) => (r.range.endColumnIndex - 1) == i)}${r.range.endRowIndex}`]);
  }

  let cleanDupeProtectedRange = (p, userSheetID) => {
    let protectedRangeIds = p.map(x => `{"deleteProtectedRange": {"protectedRangeId":${x[0]}}}`)
    let requestbuilder = `{"requests": [${protectedRangeIds.join(',')}]}`
    return Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(requestbuilder, userSheetID);
  }

  let pullExistingProtectedRanges = spreadsheetData.sheets.map(p => getReadableRanges(p));

  let protectRange = pullExistingProtectedRanges.flat().reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
    const existingItem = accumulator.find(item => item[1] === currentValue[1]);
    if (!existingItem) {
      accumulator.push(currentValue);
    }
    return accumulator;
  }, []);

  var rangeToRemoved = pullExistingProtectedRanges.flat().filter(y => !protectRange.join('*').match(y[0]));

  try {
    cleanDupeProtectedRange(rangeToRemoved, userSheetID)
  } catch {
    console.log('No duplicate found')
  }

}

function UnlockFriday() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXXXXXXXXXXXX');
  spreadsheet.getRange('C8:D60').activate();
  var allProtections =
    spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  var matchingProtection1 = allProtections.find(existingProtection => existingProtection.getRange().getA1Notation() == 'C8:D60');
  if (!matchingProtection1) return;
  matchingProtection1.remove();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var checkbox = ss.getRange("AE9").getValue();
  if (checkbox == true) {
    ss.getRange("AE9").setValue("false");
  }
}

Step on how to use the Sheet API advanced service:

Add the Google Sheet API Advance service:




Demo

Sample user sheet with duplicate protected ranges



After running the checkDupes function


References
Enable Advances Google Service for Sheets API
Named & protected ranges Sheets API

Thank you for your reply.  Anxious to give it a try!  Please know I'm not a programmer but know enough to get by.  I put in my sheet ID in line two.  and then try to save.  Syntax Error: Unexpected token '{' line 8.  Also, in line 14 after requestbuilder should I replace with the same sheet ID as in line 2?

@PT109 I've updated my answer where I tweaked your actual script to show you how you can use the sample checkDupes function.

Works perfectly!!  You are the man!!  Thank you so much, I have learned a lot about the Advanced Google Service for Google Sheet API.  Definitely much quicker.

Plus your solution prevents a duplicate from even happening in the first place.  The second answer deletes duplicates on the backend.  Your's is much better and more efficient.  Thanks again.

Was able to piece together an answer that works.  Multiple instances of same range protected cells are all deleted. Checkmark box is changed from "true" to "false".
function UnlockFriday() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
  var protections = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C8:D60').activate();
  for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
    if (protections[i].getDescription() == 'AA Lock Friday Cells') {
protections[i].remove();
    }
    }  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var checkbox = ss.getRange("AE9").getValue();
  if(checkbox==true){
    ss.getRange("AE9").setValue("false");
    }
 } 

